# ASP.Net MVC RedirectToAction with anchor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, fragment-identifier

I have the following problem:
For example I have route like this:

```
routes.Add(new Route("forums/thread/{threadOid}/last", new MvcRouteHandler())
           Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(
             new { controller = "Thread", action ="ShowThreadLastPostPage"}),
        Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(new { threadOid = @"^\d+$" })
    }
);
```

Is there a way using RedirectToAction method navigate to the URL like this:

> `forums/thread/{threadOid}/last#postOid`

Comment: For ASP.NET MVC Core, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/55741977/11683.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

I think you should use the `Redirect` method along with `Url.RouteUrl` to accomplish it.

```
return Redirect(Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "Thread", action = "ShowThreadLastPostPage", threadOid = threadId }) + "#" + postOid);
```

Comment: Like this answer, but doesn't this cause a render to the client then a new request to the server followed by another render? If so, is there another way to avoid this?

Comment: This solution is very difficult to test, but it may well be the only solution.

Answer (score 24):

Another alternative with `Url.Action`:

```
return Redirect(Url.Action("ShowThreadLastPostPage", "Thread", new { threadOid = threadOid }) + "last#" + postOid);
```