# Retain jquery tab position after Post action in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction, jquery-tabs, routevalues

I have a page with jquery tabs in which the user can update their Profile, Password, General in each tab.

When a user update the details in "General" tab, the post action will be called and it should retain the "General" tab back.

It can be accessed directly by calling like `http://localhost:8742/User/Settings/10#General`. In the url `10` is the user id.

How can i use the `RedirectToAction` in my asp.net mvc (C#) application to retain the "General" Tab.

I have tried like:

```
return RedirectToAction("Settings#General", new { Id= _user.Id });
```

But the above one doesn't works as it has `routeValues` in it. How can i retain the jquery tab after post action using RedirectToAction with `routeValues` ? Or How can i rewrite my above RedirectToAction to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602788/asp-net-mvc-redirecttoaction-with-anchor) for a possible solution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is exactly i m looking for.