# Add An Anchor To RedirectToAction's Result?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extension-methods, mvccontrib

I'm trying to create an extension method similar to [MVCContrib's RedirectToAction method](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/c0a43d6843a7#src%2fMVCContrib%2fControllerExtensions.cs) by creating a method that will take an #anchor argument and add it to the Url. I am familiar with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602788/asp-net-mvc-redirecttoaction-with-anchor) but it's not strongly typed. It's also possible to add values to the query-string, but that won't work for an anchor.

```
public static RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction<T>(this Controller controller, Expression<Action<T>> action, string anchor) where T : Controller
{
   var result = new RedirectToRouteResult<T>(action);

   // how can I add the #anchor to the result's url?

   return result;
}
```

Comment: Maybe not possible? I'm not giving up. http://groups.google.com/group/mvccontrib-discuss/browse_thread/thread/f37cc5d848407e2a

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602788/asp-net-mvc-redirecttoaction-with-anchor

Comment: Not strongly typed, it uses "magic strings". I referenced that in the question.