# Using MvcContrib's strongly typed RedirectToAction with an anchor tag (hashtag)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib

I'm using MvcContrib's strongly typed RedirectToAction() to redirect from one controller action to another, while avoiding magic strings in my application flow, like so:

```
this.RedirectToAction<FooController>(c => c.Bar());
```

which in turn redirects to

```
/foo/bar/
```

... but now I'd like to be able to redirect to an URL with an anchor/hashtag at the end,  and scroll the window to the `<a name="yarrr" />` tag, like so:

```
/foo/bar/#yarrr
```

I could put the hashtag in TempData[], write it in a javascript variable and have the window scroll via javascript - but I'd rather follow convention and have the hashtag as the end of my URL.

Any ideas or home made solutions for this? 
MvcContrib doesn't seem to support it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add An Anchor To RedirectToAction's Result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764318/add-an-anchor-to-redirecttoactions-result)

Comment: @nemesv, unfortunately the dupe hasn't been answered. I have answered this one as this was the first question I saw on this subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not aware of the existence of such an ActionLink overload in MvcContrib but writing one would be trivial:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using System.Web.Routing;

public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString ActionLink<TController>(
        this HtmlHelper html,
        Expression<Action<TController>> action,
        string linkText,
        object htmlAttributes,
        string fragment
    ) where TController : Controller
    {
        var routeValues = Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Internal.ExpressionHelper
            .GetRouteValuesFromExpression(action);
        return html.RouteLink(
            linkText: linkText,
            routeName: null,
            protocol: null,
            hostName: null,
            fragment: fragment,
            routeValues: routeValues,
            htmlAttributes: new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes)
        );
    }
}
```

and then in your view:

```
@(Html.ActionLink<FooController>(c => c.Bar(), "click me", null, "yarrr"))
```

---

UPDATE:

Apparently I misunderstood your question as you were looking for a `RedirectToAction` method in the controller, not inside the view. My answer is the same as previously: `I am not aware of the existence of such an RedirectToAction overload in MvcContrib but writing one would be trivial:`

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static RedirectResult RedirectToAction<TController>(
        this Controller controller,
        Expression<Action<TController>> action,
        string fragment
    ) where TController : Controller
    {
        var routeValues = Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Internal.ExpressionHelper
            .GetRouteValuesFromExpression(action);
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(controller.ControllerContext.RequestContext);
        return new RedirectResult(
            UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(
                routeName: null,
                actionName: null,
                controllerName: null,
                protocol: null,
                hostName: null,
                fragment: fragment,
                routeValues: routeValues,
                routeCollection: urlHelper.RouteCollection,
                requestContext: controller.ControllerContext.RequestContext,
                includeImplicitMvcValues: true
            )
        );
    }
}
```

and then inside your controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return this.RedirectToAction<FooController>(c => c.Bar(), "yarrr");
    }
}
```

Comment: MvcContrib's RedirectToAction is used to redirect from one controller action to another - strongly typed. I'm looking for a way to do this, just also including a hashtag as a parameter... not how to generate an actionlink link in a view. I'm sorry if this was not clear.

Comment: Something trivial for you; something very hard for me without the proper knowledge :) Thank you very much - and I learned about UrlHelper and ExpressionHelper to boot!

Comment: Can an overload be written for RedirectToAction for htmlAttributes to allow opening of a new browser tab. Please see my question. Thanks  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512413/redirecttoaction-htmlattribute-overload

Comment: @Joe, no it can't. This should happen on the client. The server doesn't know what a browser means and even less a browser tab.

Comment: +1 for `Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Internal.ExpressionHelper.GetRouteValuesFromExpression` That's awesome!

Comment: `Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Internal.ExpressionHelper` doesn't seem to exist in MVC4. Anyone got a solution for this in MVC4?

Comment: @hardywang No. I basically switched to T4MVC for solving my needs (strong typed links and redirects). http://t4mvc.codeplex.com . Try it and you won't look back.