# RedirectToAction htmlAttribute overload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to open a RedirectToAction in a new tab.  Unfortuantely there is no overload that takes a htmlAttribute as with ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink("Text", "Action", new { parameters }, new { target="_blank" })
```

Is it possible to write an overload for RedirectToAction to do this from the Action.  If so would you please post the working code for the overload.

I want to open the new tab programatically from the Action, not a link that has to be clicked. So please no answers on how to do it with an actionlink.  I already stated I know how to do that.

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Joe, why do you need to do a redirect? Why can't you just use the ActionLink to open the new tab and point it to the Action and Controller you would have redirected to?

Comment: I want to do it programatically from the Action, not a link that has to be clicked.

Comment: But if we trace the root of this action, did it start with a click on a link? What you're trying to do is a challenge. I'm searching for whether or not there's a work around first.

Comment: I'm sparing every one from the complexities of the context.  They are irrelevant.  Just looking for an answer to the simple question.  So far I haven't found an answer.  Perhaps you will have better luck.

Comment: If the redirect goes to new tab, where does current thread go? Wherever that is, could you include JQuery that opens a new tab on $(Ready)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open mvc view in new window from controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509616/open-mvc-view-in-new-window-from-controller)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unfortunately there is no mechanism server side to open a new tab/window. This has to be done client side. The server is simply sending back an http response to the browser, and there is no special message in the http protocol to open a new tab/window. Somebody wrote a workaround for ASP.NET that basically executes a client side script after the redirect, you can take a look [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2007/09/25/response-redirect-into-a-new-window-with-extension-methods.aspx)

Comment: The link was rather complicated, it might be useful, I didn't get into it.  The rest of your answer is correct though