# How do you redirect to an anchor within a particular action

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I tried using

```
return RedirectToAction("List#"+Name.Substring(0,1));
```

but I get a 404 error and the address bar suggest that I am looking for List%23A.

**EDIT**
"List" is the action name, and I would like to redirect directly to the First Letter anchor.

How do I pass the number sign?

Comment: You actually have an action named "List#something"?

Comment: He might be trying to move to an anchor...

Comment: I realize that, but the method takes an action name, not an action name plus arbitrary extra data to add to the URL.

Comment: So the question really is, "How to you redirect to an anchor within a particular action."

Comment: The List is the action name. I would like to redirect to the "List"action, on the (Whatever First Letter) anchor. Yes Servy. Thanks

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/602801/

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.Net MVC RedirectToAction with anchor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602788/asp-net-mvc-redirecttoaction-with-anchor)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [GenerateUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703653.aspx) static method:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    string url = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(
        null,                     // routeName
        "List",                   // actionName
        null,                     // controllerName
        null,                     // protocol
        null,                     // hostName
        "abc",                    // fragment <- that's what you are interested in
        null,                     // routeValues
        RouteTable.Routes,        // routeCollection
        Request.RequestContext,   // requestContext
        true                      // includeImplicitMvcValues
    );
    return Redirect(url);
}
```

should redirect to:

```
/currentController/List#abc
```