# How do I do the equivilent of '/controller/action/1#myid' with RedirectToAction?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have a jquery-ui tabbed display to show some data and I would like to link to specific pages within it when returning from some actions that I have.

I currently have this

```
return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller", new { id = model.ID});
```

which results in this

```
/controller/action/1
```

what is the best way to achieve this?

```
/controller/action/1#mytab
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.Net MVC RedirectToAction with anchor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602788/asp-net-mvc-redirecttoaction-with-anchor)

Comment: Ah yes, I had forgotten it was called an anchor, that makes finding a solution much quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is duplicated but for anyone who finds their way here first:

```
return Redirect(
            Url.RouteUrl(new 
            { 
                controller = "MyControllerName", 
                action = "MyActionName", 
                id = model.CustomerID 
            }) + "#mytabid");
```