# Return back to exactly where i was in Page

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I own this site: http://www.sohjel.ir ; I've implemented an option called: "Watch Bag", using ASP.NET Core 2.1  MVC Session.
And my problem is: I want to return back to exactly where I click "Add To Watch Bag" in that page after I click this button and adding that lesson to "Watch Bag" instead of returning back to "Begin of Page".
How do I do that?!
Note that I've used this code in my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int id)
{
    List<int> lstViewBag = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<int>>("sjViewBag");
    if (lstViewBag == null)
    {
        lstViewBag = new List<int>();
    }
    lstViewBag.Add(id);
    HttpContext.Session.Set("sjViewBag", lstViewBag);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "Customer" });
}
```

Comment: You can use an anchor, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602788/asp-net-mvc-redirecttoaction-with-anchor

Comment: Or.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484463/how-do-i-maintain-scroll-position-in-mvc (look at the not-accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using first comment (By: mxmissile) in:
[Return back to exactly where i was in Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55104744/return-back-to-exactly-where-i-was-in-page)
And first solution (By: mgebhard) in:
https://forums.asp.net/p/2153690/6254332.aspx?return+back+to+exactly+where+I+click

So, In "Index" action method I used this code instead:
**return Redirect(Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }) + "#" + id);**
And in its view I used this code:
id="@lesson.Id" …
And worked for me.