# Redirect to div in page with #

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to redirect to a certain div of a webpage after handling some data in a controller. Is their any way to add the '#' to the end of the url? Or should I handle it with javascript?

Example:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(ViewModel model){
    ....
    return RedirectToAction("Info", new { id = model.Id, "#" = "item_55" });
}
```

=> Should redirect to /Info/id=4#item_55

Comment: instead of this, render the page normally i.e `RedirectToAction` and upon landing on that page in `document.ready` function use `JQuery` to scroll to appropriate section i.e `#`

Comment: @Aarif why use JavaScript and jQuery for something that’s natively supported by browsers?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`RedirectToAction` has an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoaction?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_RedirectToAction_System_String_System_String_System_Object_System_String_) that allows you to specify the fragment. Here's an example:

```
return RedirectToAction("Info", "Controller", new { id = model.Id }, "item_55");
```

Note that you also need to specify the controller as one of the arguments, as I've done above.